# Spark - what happened to the data in memory after action operation in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, memory, pyspark

I know spark use lazy operation. My question is that when I read the csv file as a spark dataframe and I do one transformation like below, what happened to the data in memory(RAM) after action operation.

```
df = spark.read.csv('example.csv')
df1 = df.withColumn("Y", df["X"])
df1.show()
```

After `show` operation, what happened to any intermediate results (data) in memory? does it remove from the memory? in other words If I runt df1.show() for the second time, does the spark read 'example.csv' again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think some of these concepts may be explained well with an illustrative example:

```py
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    import pyspark.sql.functions as F
    spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("test")\
        .getOrCreate()
    file_name = './test.csv'
    with open(file_name, 'w') as fp:
        fp.write('foo, bar')
        fp.write('\na, 1')
        fp.write('\nb, 2')
    df = spark.read.csv(file_name, header=True)
    df = df.withColumn('baz', F.lit('test'))
    df.show()
    with open(file_name, 'a') as fp:
        fp.write('\nc, 3')
    df.show()
```

The output is:

```
+---+----+----+
|foo| bar| baz|
+---+----+----+
|  a|   1|test|
|  b|   2|test|
+---+----+----+

+---+----+----+
|foo| bar| baz|
+---+----+----+
|  a|   1|test|
|  b|   2|test|
+---+----+----+
```

Indicating the data is not re-read from the file - if it was, we would have the new row (`(c, 3)`) which was written.

For an explanation, if you navigate to the Spark UI (`localhost:4040` while running locally) before calling `df.show()`, you will notice there is a job listed for reading the file, along with a corresponding DAG.

[image]
[image]

This indicates the dataframe being read into memory is an action (as in, not lazily evaluated), and the file won't be re-read unless explicitly told to with another call to `spark.read.csv`.

However, subsequent calculations performed after reading the dataframe into memory are not cached unless explicitly told to, using `df.cache()`. For example, if we were to add the following to the previous snippet:

```py
    df.filter(F.col('foo') == 'a').count()
    df.filter(F.col('foo') == 'a').show()
```

The computations for performing the same filter will be repeated, whereas if we add a `cache` call:

```py
    df.filter(F.col('foo') == 'a').cache()
    df.filter(F.col('foo') == 'a').count()
    df.filter(F.col('foo') == 'a').show()
```

The computations will be saved in memory. This can be seen by the difference in plans (see images below) - specifically, in the `cache` case, notice there is an `InMemoryTableScan` step.

[image][image]

Which, when navigated into, provides more details about the query which has been cached, as well as the action where it was first computed:

[image]

It may be hard to see in the image, but notice "[Cached
count at.." at the end of the query information, as `count` was the first action function to be called after calling `cache` (**Note**: calling `cache` itself doesn't perform an action - it just ensures that when an action function is called such as `count` or `show`, the data will be cached for subsequent actions).

Comment: just one question: in "If you navigate to the Spark UI (localhost:4040 while running locally) before calling df.show(), you will notice there is a job listed for reading the file, along with a corresponding DAG", before calling df.show() refers the first one or the second one?

Comment: Another question - how we can remove the data after the file being read to memory after calling df.show() to free up space in memory?

Comment: Sure thing! Regarding your first question, I meant the first `df.show()`. Regarding the second question, Spark should handle memory allocation and management on different executors, so you should not have an issue - are you observing memory issues?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have not seen memory issue. I am curious after ```df. show()``` if I read another file for example, 'test_new.csv' and create a new data frame called dh if I do ```dh.show()```, does memory still keep data from both files.? or spark manage the space the memory, for example, If not enough memory for reading 'test_new.csv', does spark remove the data related to df from the memory to read the data related to dh

Answer (score 0):

> any intermediate results (data) in memory?

What intermediate result do you mean? Spark will perform optimizes analysis automatically and pack a bunch of operations if there is some unnecessary intermediate result, it does not need to calculate it out. For example in your code, line1 and line2 do not take action until line 3 is executed.
That means until line2, `df` and `df1` are kind of the "intermediate result" I guess you mean. But they actually do not even been calculated. So they are not in memory at all. The file read operation also does not perform.

However, it is different for line3, cause line3 explicitly checks the value of the `df1`. Then `df1` could not be optimized out and its value needs to be calculated. And `df1` will be in memory with its values.

> does it remove from the memory?

As line3 explicitly views `df1`'s value, the variable `df1` would be in memory.

> does the spark read 'example.csv' again?

No. When calling `df1.show` again, Spark directly reads the value from the memory.

Comment: Thank you! if df1 values are in memory, why we need to cache data in memory in spark sometime?  if we have more transformations, for example df2,  which can not be packed with df1, then  the values of df1 and the values of df2 will be saved in memory and causes memory issue. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

DAG is constructed based on operations on the data frame. When an action is encountered the spark engine executes the DAG. In your case, upon calling df.show() for the 2nd time, spark will re-read the 'example.csv' again as the data frame was not persisted/cached.